# Lazy load with inline images

Tags: media

It looks like all popular lazyload modules only work with Images. I would like to get lazyload to work on my inline images (images inserted with Media/FCKEditor).

Do any modules support this? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is an old question, but I think this may help others with the same issue.*

I recently contributed a module to Drupal community for lazy-loading inline images (and iframes). 
Once the module is installed, the filter needs to be enabled in desired text-formats.

It requires no changes to the existing content.

**Lazy-load**
https://www.drupal.org/project/lazy